# parent and child nodes interchange xslt

Tags: xslt

The below is the xml code I have which in input to XSLT, XSLT code is provided and I've provided the expected output and area where I'm stuck. This is an example about Assets and respective base metres.

```
            <BaseMeter>
                <MeterName>Meter description</MeterName>
                <MeterCode>Meter1</MeterCode>
                <ASSETID>
                    <Name>Airco Unit</Name>
                    <Code>ID1</Code>
                </ASSETID>
            </BaseMeter>
 <BaseMeter>
                <MeterName>Meter description</MeterName>
                <MeterCode>Meter2</MeterCode>
                <ASSETID>
                    <Name>Airco Unit</Name>
                    <Code>ID1</Code>
                </ASSETID>
            </BaseMeter>
```

The transformed XML should be like below The actual transformed xml code through xslt is also provided in the below.

```
<Asset>
   AssetID
   AssetName
   <Meter>
       MeterID (eg. Meter 1)
       MeterName
   <Meter>
   <Meter>
       MeterID (eg. Meter 2)
       MeterName
   <Meter>
```

I have used the below XSLT

```
 <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each-group select="BaseMeter" group-by="AssetID/Code">
            <Asset ID="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>

            </Asset>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>
```

And output is this, but again Asset ID and name are captured as childs to Asset tag, how to remove them so that they do not appear in the output or transformed xml`enter code here`

```
<Asset ID="000244">
   <BaseMeter>

                <MeterName>Meter Name</MeterName>
                <MeterCode>0040</MeterCode>
                <AssetID>
                    <Name>Airco Unit</Name>
                    <Code>000244</Code>
                </AssetID>
            </BaseMeter>
```

This is the issue I'm facing.. will be really nice if someone can help me out. I have used group by and unable to crack how to remove asset Id appearing again.

Comment: Are you sure that you can find InventoryItemRef in your xml?

Comment: I have edited the xslt

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML (no single root element). Therefore the output cannot be what you claim it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output looks strange, so there is a template that produces more converntional output:

```
<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each-group select="BaseMeter" group-by="ASSETID/Code">
        <Asset ID="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <Meter>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="MeterName|MeterCode"/>
                </Meter>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Asset>
    </xsl:for-each-group>    
</xsl:template>
```

result:

```
<Asset ID="ID1">
   <Meter>
      <MeterName>Meter description</MeterName>
      <MeterCode>Meter1</MeterCode>
   </Meter>
   <Meter>
      <MeterName>Meter description</MeterName>
      <MeterCode>Meter2</MeterCode>
   </Meter>
</Asset>
```

Comment: No, that is **not** the result, and cannot be the result.